# Как отслеживать нажатые клавиши в консоли Linux?

Tags: terminal, консоль, c++11, c++, linux

В сети море примеров как отслеживать на Си под Windows нажатые клавиши, включая стрелки. Указывается `getchar()`, `getch()` и библиотека (борлондовская) `conio.h`.

Меня интересует пример кода на С++ и под Linux, в консоли. Чтобы в консоли при нажатии стрелок происходили нужные мне действия.

Примеров, к сожалению, не нашёл. :(

ASCII коды знаю. Какой функцией или как правильно считать символ с клавиатуры?

Желательно, чтобы без дополнительного нажатия Enter после нажатой клавиши. Нажал букву или стрелку — сразу произошло нужное действие.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По вопросу чувствую, что потом нужны будут и цветные символы, и какие то дополнительные вещи (позиционирование курсора). Поэтому рекомендую сразу использовать библиотеку ncurses.

Чуточку погуглив, нашел хороший [туториал](http://alexber220.narod.ru/ncurses/). Буквально на [второй странице](http://alexber220.narod.ru/ncurses/page2.htm) описано как считывать нажатия клавиш.

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать. Цветные символы можно сделать консольными кодами. Например, cout << "\E[01;31m" << "Red text" << "\E[01;0m";

Comment: да, это можно. Но некоторые терминалы не поддерживают цвет - нужно делать проверки. Некоторые терминалы поддерживают только 16 цветов. А в ncurses много удобных функций уже есть.

Кстати, классический пример, который сделан на ncurses - mc.

Comment: В ваших примерах используется Си (gcc) и getch(). У меня уже есть рабочие примеры на Си. Но я хочу задачу решить на С++.

Comment: @Infum Никто не мешает использовать этот же код и в с++. Он будет работать. При желании можно написать обертку с классами и поэтессами.

Если же хочется решат на чистом с++ - то это невозможно, все равно придется использовать особенности терминала и в конце концов напишете свою библиотеку.

Answer (score 0):

[[@Infum](/users/20319/infum)](/users/20319/infum), если "*как это на самом деле устроено*" интересно, то для понимания основ работы с терминалом начните с чтения `man termios`.

Также можете набрать в гугле

```
unix Terminal I/O
```

и почитать, например, [здесь](http://www.sbin.org/doc/unix-faq/programmer/faq_4.html#SEC47)

--

Кстати, в интересующем Вас разрезе различия между Си и C++ минимальны (на уровне "придирок" компилятора).

Не думаю, что наплодить кучу классов -- это плодотворная идея для решения практических задач в данной области.